# Jquery Code works on Firefox but not in Chrome & Opera

Tags: jquery

I wonder this code does not trigger in Chrome. It works as expected in FireFox.

```js
$("#filter-price :checkbox").on("click", function() {
  $("#product-results").empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="items" id="filter-price">
  <li class="item ">
    <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="0-20"><span>$0 - $20 <span class="count"></span>  </span>
                   </label>
  </li>


  <li class="item ">
    <label>
               <input type="checkbox" value="20-50"><span>$20 - $50 <span class="count"></span>  </span>
              </label>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Check console for errors

Comment: There is no error in console. It works fine in Firefox

Comment: Works fine in FF but error in O and Chrome means the script may blocked by browser due to security issues. Check console of chrome and O

Comment: Please also post the html code of the element with id 'product-results'

Comment: @Sagar, no errors in console of chrome

Comment: @Fabian, even a alert('test'); is also not working to replace # Id 'product-results'.empty();

Comment: Please check this link online http://womensebookstore.com/1/category.asp?cat=23 in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Does `console.log($('#filter-price :checkbox'))` return an element when applied before the posted script?

Comment: Javascript is in http://womensebookstore.com/1/js/scroll_loading.js

Comment: Update with the html code as Fabian said. So that we can diagnose it easily

Comment: @Fabian works on Firefox but not in Chrome. Here is the response in consolelog  Object { 0: <input>, 1: <input>, 2: <input>, 3: <input>, length: 4, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → category.asp, selector: "#filter-price :checkbox" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is executed before the html elements `input:checkbox` are available in Chrome/Opera.

Wrap your JavaScript into a [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(function() {
    console.log('Register click event on:', $("#filter-price :checkbox"));
    $("#filter-price :checkbox").on("click", function() {
      console.log('Click event recognized', {checkbox: $(this) elToEmpty: $("#product-results")});
      $("#product-results").empty();
    });
});
```

Comment: Next time use `console.log` to identify defective selectors :)